# How to GET a response with a given URL and a username and password?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, xmlhttprequest

I have been asked to load drop down boxes from an OLAP server and the server credentials are given. They are as follows

- url
- HTTP Method - POST
- auth user: abc123
- auth pwd: api123
- REQ/RES content type/charset = application/json; charset=UTF-8

The following is the code I have written:

```
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url= "http://someIPAddress/getData";

alert("Before Posting data");
hr.open("POST",url,true);
alert("Connection open");

document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Loading...";

hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    alert("Entered callback function...");
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        alert(return_data);
    }
    else{
        alert("There is a connection issue");
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
    }
}
ajaxReq.send("POST",url,function populate(){
    alert("Request received");
})
}
```

These are the exact data provided (except the url, username and password. Am not disclosing it here the actual data)

I am trying to use the `XMLHttpRequest()` by specifying the URL, POST and the call back function. How to pass the username and password here so that it responds you with data

When I try to access the url, it asked me for User name: and Password:

I dont know how to append the credentials with the url, as I am not specified the exact key to the values. Could you please help. I think I am missing out on something

Answer (score 1):

You need to send an `Authorization` header with the request. This header value consists in the username followed by a ':' and the password, encoded as base64:

```
hr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
```

`btoa()` encodes a string as base64.

Comment: Thanks, for the quick response, so am i suppose to define the btoa function? Also is there 100 perc assurance that the username and password is being passed like this only to the server?

Comment: `btoa()` is a stardard javascript function. You don't need to define it. When you say *passed like this only to the server*, you mean that no one else can see it? If it's this, then the answer is: depends on whether you're using HTTPS. If you aren't, anyone can see the the request, and getting the username an password is as simple as decoding the base64 string of the `Authorization` header. But be aware that this happens, also, when you insert your username and password in the browser login dialog box. If you're concerned about security, always use HTTPS.

Comment: Still not getting any response. The onreadychange function is not being called.

Comment: No error, just that the onreadychange function isnt getting invoked

Comment: Hmm, well, you are creating a `hr` object but are calling `send` in `ajaxReq`. Maybe is this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an URI like `http://user:pass@someIPAddress/getData` perhaps this will be all you need. I had never tried it submitting a form but you can check